# Within group variation for categorical dependent variable

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data

I need some help.

I am trying to test within group variations but my situation seems a little bit more complex and I’m yet to find a statistical test that caters to this situation. Or perhaps I haven’t conceptualized the idea properly.

Let’s say I’m using gender to predict the likelihood of owning a gym bag. And I predict that Women are more likely to own a gym bag than men. How can I show that this relationship of women more likely to own a gym bag than men is affected by Wether the woman works out at home or not. Or wether she goes to the gym in a car or not.

there is already a positive significant result showing that women are more likely to own a gym bag than men. Now I’m interested in finding out if certain attributes of women enhance or diminish this relationship.

Comment: Logistic regression looks like the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I did consider interaction effects but concluded it might not work. Since gender is already coded 1=female and 0=male, and I am interested in the different attributes of women relative to men it breaks the assumption of moderation that requires the independent and moderating variables to be independent

Comment: So you want to compare women who work out versus women who do not work out with men irrespective of whether the men work out?

Comment: I have statistically significant result showing that women are more likely to own a gym bag than men. Now I want to find out if certain characteristics of women are more likely to own a gym bag than men. So for instance which group of women are more likely to own a gym bag then men? 1 = women who workout at home 0 = otherwise. And 1 = women who drive to work 0 = otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is the second try to give a hint.

To study how the effect of gender on owning a gym bag is affected by other factors like work out home, you could run a logistic regression with interaction between gender and work out home (and maybe more interaction terms).

Comment: Thank you for your response Michael. But if I replaced gender with workout at home, then I will be comparing women against women. I’m interested in how different women compare to men to see which attributes of women matter most relative to men. Does that make sense?

Comment: Right, I misread one of your statements in your post.